# Is it possible to redirect https to http?

Tags: https, url-rewriting, iis

I am working on a website with Comodo SSL installed. There are http: links to pages that Chrome and IE-11 complain are not secure and block access to them unless users explicitly allow them when prompted.

Although some of the links do have https equivalents, others (HuffingtonPost.com) do not. The HuffPost links are articles written by the site owner, and since I have no control over HuffPost, I believe my only recourse it to copy the articles over to his blogger site. UGH!

There is one important site I do have control over, and would like to redirect the links (that I will change from http to https) to the site without installing SSL. I tried using URL Rewrite to perform the https to http redirection, but even though the pattern matches it (https://thebeautyquotient.com/) the browser displays "Your connection is not private" showing https with a red diagonal line through it. I assume the URL redirection isn't working. Here's the rule:

```
            <rule name="https to http" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="https*" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{ALL_HTTP}" pattern="off" />
                </conditions>
            </rule>
```

Note I tried using Rewrite as well as redirect and also removing the condition.

Thanks for taking the time reading trough this question.

Comment: How is this different from your other question?  http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/77546/is-there-a-way-to-handle-an-ssl-site-with-links-to-non-ssl-sites

Comment: The other question seemed a little vague and I thought perhaps this technique was worth a try. Also, I am a little new to URL Rewrite and hoped someone could show me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You can't rewrite a URL from another site.   You also need to provide more information about this problem.  I have been unable to replicate the problem with Chrome.

Comment: You don't see a shield icon on the right side of the address bar? On the home page, there is scrolling area containing links. Do they resolve when clicked?

Comment: Your site is thebeautyquotient.com ?   It doesn't work with HTTPS for me.  It has an invalid cert.   When I try to browse even with the invalid cert it gives me a blank page.   I had done the testing with my own HTTPS site and Chrome.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the https site is madisonps.com

Comment: Your problem had nothing to do with HTTPS but was rather due to a syntax error.  I'm closing this so that it does not confuse people in the future that are searching for HTTPS solutions.

Comment: Sure. I would still like to know to get rid of the shield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your site is not HTTPS.   You have malformed HTML tags near your links

```
<li <a itemprop="url" href="http://www.huffingtonpost.com/robert-Tornambe-md/melanoma_b_850558.html" target="_blank" class="articleLink"><img itemprop="thumbnailUrl" src="images/huffpost.png" alt="huffpost-article: Malignant Melanoma: The Silent Killer by Dr. Robert Tornambe" />
```

Should be:

```
<li><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.huffingtonpost.com/robert-Tornambe-md/melanoma_b_850558.html" target="_blank" class="articleLink"><img itemprop="thumbnailUrl" src="images/huffpost.png" alt="huffpost-article: Malignant Melanoma: The Silent Killer by Dr. Robert Tornambe" />
```

You are missing the closing angle bracket (`>`) on your `li` tag.  I cannot click on your links because of that.

Comment: Thanks so much! Saved me a lot of work. There is still a shield on my address bar. Yours too? Clicking it displays a red diagonal line across https:

Comment: You are not loading jQuery over HTTPS.   Here is the warning that Firefox gives me: `Loading mixed (insecure) active content on a secure page "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"`

Comment: Thanks again. Can you explain how you found that in Firefox? I specified https, but am still seeing the shield, so there must be more occurs somewhere.